# read last line and convert to numeric

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a text file which contains headers, trailers and detail records.

format:

```
H20161010XXX                        // record length: 880  
D<---details----total length 880--->
D<---details----total length 880--->
T2016101020161010          00004    // record length : 880
```

i want to parse '00004' and perform some calculations on it.

I have read the trailer record but I am not able to parse 00004 from it

```
trailer=`tac $FILE | grep -m 1 '.'`
echo $trailer 
count=$(trailer:29:5)
echo $count
```

output:

```
T2016101020161010          00004
```

I am not able to pick out 00004.

The start position and the length of the 00004 is fixed and I can hard code it. Also I want to store it in a variable and perform arithmetic operations on them.

I am writing a shell script using ksh. 
Many thanks !

Comment: If you're allowed to use `grep` and `tac`, can you use `awk`? e.g. `awk 'END {print $2}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get $trailer:

```
count=$(echo $trailer | cut -d' ' -f2)
echo $count
```

Answer (score 0):

Use curly braces to get the substring:

```
count=${trailer:29:5}
```

Note your copy/pasted example looks more correct using  "${trailer:27:5}".